# Python save file with different extension

Tags: python, file-extension

I am aware of the os.path.splitext(file) function in Python, but this is changing the extenson of the existing file. I need to preserve the original file with its Extension as read file and create another file with another Extension as write file. 
For Example:

```
A = "File.inp"
pre, ext = os.path.splitext(A)
B = os.rename(A, pre + ".PRE")
with open("B" , 'w') as f1:
    with open("A",'r') as f2:
...
```

This command changes the Extension of the file form .inp to .PRE but without preserving the original file "File.inp". Any ideas or Solutions how can I preserve the original file with ist original Extension?

Comment: What you expect when using `os.rename()`? Just remove that line. Then when you pass the new file name to `open()` a file with that name will be created.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify your question - do you want to just copy the original file with different extension or you want to create a new file with different extension, read from original file, process what you read and write in the new file.

Comment: @buran: I need to create a new file which has the name of the original file but another extension. The original file will then be used as read file and the new file as write file, with other format of the information contained in the original file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
base_file = "File.inp"
name, ext = base_file.split('.')
new_file = '{}.{}'.format(name, 'PRE')

with open(base_file , 'r') as f1:
    with open(new_file, 'w') as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly as soon as you use "os.rename()" or "os.replace()" it changes the original file and doesn't just "copy" it.

You could use shutil and this code:

```
import os
import shutil
A = "File.inp"
pre, ext = os.path.splitext(A)
B = pre + ".PRE"
shutil.copy(A,B)
with open(B , 'w') as f1:
    with open(A,'r') as f2:
        ...
```

Comment: No need to copy the file. When you open it with `w` mode it will be overwriten.

Comment: He wants to "only read" the "File.inp" file to get information to "write" in the "File.PRE" file.

Comment: then I guess he can switch the `open(..., 'w')` and `open(..., 'r')` to fix it

Comment: Depending what OP wants. And he wants to read from `File.inp`, do something with what they read and WRITE in the new file. At least is what their question says and snippet shows... And anyway what is the point to read same file content twice - from 2 files???

Answer (score 0):

not too clear. So you want to keep the original file and create a copy of it with a different extension?
I guess `shutil.copy(origin, destination)` should work

Comment: No need to copy the file. When you open it with `w` mode (as in OP code) it will be overwriten.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not have enough reputation to comment, so I'm adding an improvement to Dmitry's answer here.

He answered the question, but for other users learning from this thread, his answer will break (ValueError) if there are other dots in the file name.

rsplit(), which operates on the string in reverse order, with 1 as an argument, will split the string on the last occurrence of the delimiter.

```
base_file = "FileV0.1.2.inp"
name, ext = base_file.rsplit('.', 1)
new_file = '{}.{}'.format(name, 'PRE')

with open(base_file , 'r') as f1:
    with open(new_file, 'w') as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
```